# If there is a diffeomorphism from an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ onto a submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb R^d$, then $M$ is open

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, inverse-function-theorem

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $O\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$
- $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary
- $f:O\to M$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism

> How can we conclude that $M$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$?

I think it's easy to make a stupid mistake here, since the road from the assumption to the conclusion is subtle.

First of all, if $M_i$ is any embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$, $g:M_1\to M_2$ is bijective and $C^1$-differentiable at $x_1\in M_1$ and $g^{-1}$ is $C^1$-differentiable at $g(x_1)$, then

1. $g^{-1}\circ g$ is $C^1$-differentiable at $x_1$ and $$\operatorname{id}_{T_{x_1}\:M_1}=T_{g(x_1)}(g^{-1})\circ T_{x_1}(g).$$
2. $g\circ g^{-1}$ is $C^1$-differentiable at $g(x_1)$ and $$\operatorname{id}_{T_{g(x_1)}\:M_2}=T_{x_1}(g)\circ T_{g(x_1)}(g^{-1}).$$
3. $T_{x_1}(g)$ is an isomorphism from $T_{x_1}\:M_1$ onto $T_{g(x_1)}\:M_2$ with $${T_{x_1}(g)}^{-1}=T_{g(x_1)}(g^{-1}).$$
4. $T_{g(x_1)}(g^{-1})$ is an isomorphism from $T_{g(x_1)}\:M_2$ onto $T_{x_1}\:M_1$ with $${T_{g(x_1)}(g^{-1})}^{-1}=T_{x_1}(g).$$

> Now I wonder whether we really need to argue with the implicit function theorem. Maybe this is too complicated, but we could do the following (and hopefully I'm not missing a subtlety): Let $x\in O$. Since $T_x(f)$ (which is equal to the Fréchet derivative ${\rm D}f(x)$, since $f$ is defined on an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$) is an isomorphism, it is - in particular - injective and hence there is an $\mathbb R^d$-open neighborhood $N_1\subseteq O$ of $x$ and an $\mathbb R^d$-open neighborhood $N_2\subseteq M$ of $f(x)$ such that $\left.f\right|_{N_1}$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $N_1$ onto $N_2$. So, $f(x)$ is an interior point of $M$ and hence we're done.
>
> Am I missing something in my argumentation? And, more interestingly, do we really need to argue with the inverse function theorem, if we already know what I wrote about $g$ in general?

Comment: What is $O$ ?  Is it an open ?

Comment: If $O$ is open, then it is a dimension $d$ manifold, and by diffeomorphism $M$ is $d$ dimensional submanifold, so it is open in $\mathbb{R}^d$ outside its boundary. More over, diffeomorphism preserves boundaries and since $O$ has no boundary, $M$ has no boundary as well

Comment: @AlexL I'm sorry, yes, $O$ is open.

Comment: @AlexL At which point is it crucial that $f$ is not only a homeomorphism, but a diffeomorphism? And in your "boundary preservation" argument, aren't we encountering exactly the subtlety mentioned in the question? To be precise, if $h$ is any homeomorphism between topological spaces $E_i$ and $B_1\subseteq E_1$, then $h(B_1^\circ)=h(B_1)^\circ$ and $h(\partial B_1)=\partial h(B_1)$, but this only yields that $h(B_1^\circ)$ is open in $E_2$ (and not in an ambient space as we would need in the context of the question, where $E_2=M$.)

Comment: I think you don't really need a diffeomorphism, a homeomorphism should be enough but it is more subtle to handle and to show that boundaries are preserved.

Comment: I said "M is a $d$ dimensional submanifold, so $M \setminus \partial M$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^d$" because for a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^d$ without boundary, being open in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is equivalent to have dimension $d$ as a (abstract) manifold

Comment: So, okay, your argument is that $O$ is a $d$-dimensional $C^\infty$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ without boundary and hence we know that any $C^\alpha$-diffeomorphism ($\alpha\in\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$) $T$ from $O$ to $T(O)$ will map $O$ to a $d$-dimensional $C^\alpha$-submanifold without boundary. But any $d$-dimensional $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ and hence $T(\Omega)$ must be open. Right?

Comment: Any $d$ dimensional submanifold of $R^d$ without boundary is an open set of $R^d$

Comment: @AlexL That's what I wrote, isn't it? So you agree that $T(O)$ is open?

Comment: Yes, it is open in $\mathbb{R}^d$